# GCC Makefile Error : No rule to make target 'put.h', needed by 'straps.o'. Stop

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, qemu, include-path

I am trying to run my makefile using make run but its getting some errors : "No rule to make target 'put.h', needed by 'straps.o'. Stop". The error is about GCC can't find the headers file(put.h) when running makefile with the text below :

In kernel directory's Makefile

```
VPATH=../../include
all : straps.o entry.o head.o
straps.o : straps.c put.h
     $(GCC) -c straps.c $(CFLAG)
entry.o : entry.S 
     $(GCC) -c entry.S $(CFLAG) 
head.o : head.S 
     $(GCC) -c head.S $(CFLAG)
```

(straps.c include"put.h" so i need to include put.h)
I am trying to include headers file in the gcc command line (by using $(GCC) -c straps.c $(CFLAG) -I../include) but still not working. Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and suggest a fix solution if possible. Thank you

My file list

```
Linux
├── arch
│   └── riscv
│       ├── kernel
│       │   ├── entry.S
│       │   ├── head.S
│       │   ├── Makefile
│       │   ├── straps.c
│       │   └── vmlinux.lds
│       └── Makefile
├── include
│   ├── put.h
│   └── test.h
├── init
│   ├── main.c
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── test.c
├── lib
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── put.c
└── Makefile
```

Main Makefile gives the variable as below :

```
export
CROSS_= riscv64-unknown-elf-
AR=${CROSS_}ar
GCC=${CROSS_}gcc
LD=${CROSS_}ld
OBJCOPY=${CROSS_}objcopy
ISA ?= rv64imafd
ABI ?= lp64
INCLUDE = -I ../include
CF = -g -O3 -march=$(ISA) -mabi=$(ABI) -mcmodel=medany -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nostdinc -static -lgcc -Wl,--nmagic -Wl,--gc-sections
CFLAG = ${CF} ${INCLUDE}
```

***Solution :
The kernel directory's Makefile Updated as below (refers to the answer given in the post below):

```
VPATH = ../../../include
CFLAG += -I../../../include
all : straps.o entry.o head.o
straps.o : straps.c put.h
        $(GCC) -c straps.c $(CFLAG)
entry.o : entry.S
        $(GCC) -c entry.S $(CFLAG)
head.o : head.S
        $(GCC) -c head.S $(CFLAG)
```

Comment: Based on your makefile it looks as if you run make from within the `lab2/arch/riscv/kernel` directory. If that's the case shouldn't you have `VPATH=../../../include` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're assuming that `VPATH` is somehow related to how the compiler locates header files.  That is definitely not the case.  `VPATH` is a **make** construct, and controls where **make** looks for prerequisites of targets appearing in the makefile.

It has absolutely nothing to do with where the *compiler* looks to find preprocessor include files.  To control that you have to add `-I` options to the compile line.

So for example use:

```
VPATH = ../../../include
CFLAG += -I../../../include
```

Comment: i removed VPATH and add the `-I` options but still shows the same problem

`all : straps.o entry.o head.o
straps.o : straps.c put.h
        $(GCC) -c straps.c $(CFLAG) + -I../../../include
entry.o : entry.S
        $(GCC) -c entry.S $(CFLAG)
head.o : head.S
        $(GCC) -c head.S $(CFLAG)`

Comment: You are using a non-standard variable `CFLAG` not `CFLAGS`; I updated my answer.  Note, you can't put this variable setting in the parent makefile: you have to put it in the makefile that actually compiles the files.  Variables are not inherited by sub-makes, unless you export them.

Comment: Actually you need BOTH the `-I` and the VPATH; I somehow didn't notice you had listed the .h file as a prerequisite.

Comment: I updated my parent makefile which is in the lab2 directory.
Ok i try the new solution you updated

Answer (score 0):

The dependency list following "straps.o:" must refer to objects you have rules to actualy make within the makefile. In that makefile you have rules to make straps.o, entry.o, and head.o, but not put.h. Or straps.c for that matter.

Comment: but straps.c include "put.h", so i have to rules put.h in the makefile to generate straps.o

Comment: This answer would be more clear if you provided a sample of the makefile along with your description.

Comment: @PaulSCoder I added the Makefile which probably run the whole program